# Username and password verification in .NET Core the best practice

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm new to programming, and especially .NET Core. I'm very confused over password verification. My password field in the database is hashed. What is the safe way—and perhaps best practice—in .NET Core to verify the username and password?

Currently, I get the username and password from a binding model on my controller action:

```cs
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
```

My approach is to hash the `user.password` and then, along with the username, query the database to see if the credentials match an existing user. Is this the right way?

Comment: I recommend you check out Identity instead of implementing these things yourself :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @juunas thanks i read that but i have no idea in this part var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password); which checks the password ,which part it connects to database to check ?there is not query to database

Comment: The user manager there uses other classes to interact with the database. Under the covers I think it creates a salt + Bcrypt hash and the hash gets stored in the database.

Comment: @ilmagnifico: in this example you are creating a user, not logging in! to login, use SignInManager

Comment: @juunas its a database first project the user and passwords are already in DB with md5,i dont need to strore anything i just need to verify

Comment: @RicardoPeres in singleManager where is the connection to database to query,i did not find it on the internet really

Comment: Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: You say the passwords in the database are in MD5 format. That's a good sign that you probably shouldn't be rolling your own solution. MD5 is not a proper hashing algorithm to use for security purposes. It's been busted for years. The first sentence on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) even states that.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this. The answer is no, this is not the right way. In general it is better to leave security to the experts and use what they come up with.

First, you are only solving the authentication problem, but not the authorization problem. How do you ensure that nobody bypasses the login page and directly uses your app without login?

And secondly, and MD5 hash is no longer be used for authentication. There are many traps like this that you need to avoid.